# Looping through javascript object and output results in same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter', '.grid-img-hover', function() {
 var container = $(this);
 var jobId = container.parent().find('.title-wrap-hidden').text();

    $.ajax({
            url: 'db_client_job_name_lookup.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{
               jobId: jobId
                 },
               success: function(data) {
               //console.log(data.client_name[0][0][0]['name']);
                container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="job-name">'+ data.portfolio_item_name  +
                     '</p><p class="client-name">'+ data.client_name[0][0][0]['name']  +'</p>');
                  //  container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="client-name">'+ data.result.client_name  +'</p>');
                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     // error
                     alert(errorThrown);
                   }
                  });

                  });
```

Hello, I have this line of code and I want to loop through `data.client_name[0][0][0]['name']` and output its values in the same `<p class="client-name"></p>` tag. The index would change in the middle of `data.client` like so `(data.client_name[0][$index][0]['name'])`. How could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: If I get it correct then why can't you use for loop with $index as increment value for loop . what is the structure of your data.client_name[0][0][0]['name']

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 I've updated the code to show structure, I only want to loop over the data.client_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.grid-img-hover', function() {
                      var container = $(this);
                      var jobId = container.parent().find('.title-wrap-hidden').text();

                      $.ajax({
                       url: 'db_client_job_name_lookup.php',
                       type: 'POST',
                       dataType: 'json',
                       data: {
                         jobId: jobId
                       },
                       success: function(data) {
                         var client_names_text;
                         var clients_array = [];
                         function make_clients(){
                           for (var i = 0; i < data.client_name[0].length; i++) {
                                clients_array.push(data.client_name[0][i][0]['name']);
                           }
                           client_names_text = clients_array.join(',');
                           return client_names_text;
                         }
                         //console.log(data.client_name[0][0][0]['name']);
                         container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="job-name">'+ data.portfolio_item_name  +
                         '</p><p class="client-name">'+ make_clients()  +'</p>');
                      //  container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="client-name">'+ data.result.client_name  +'</p>');
                       },
                       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         // error
                         alert(errorThrown);
                       }
                      });

                      });
```

Ok, I got this working by creating a function to do the heavy lifting, here working code block.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you meant ?

```
for (i = 0; i < data.client_name[0].length; i++) { 
    container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="job-name">'+ data.portfolio_item_name +
'</p><p class="client-name">'+ data.client_name[0][i][0]['name']  +'</p>');
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code to show the entire structure, I only want to loop over the data.client_name section not the data.portfolio_item_name part of it, so I have more than one client for some jobs so I want to show all clients.

Comment: any other tips on how I could do this?:-)